# Plot multiple columns of a csv with dataframe, but many of them has an equal label name

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataset and want to plot each class agregated in one plot. Each column correponds to one class that is named as one, two, three, four, five or six. But for some reason this names are getting updated like one.1, one.2, three.5, three.6; As forementioned I just want a plot of one especific class, example: all columns of class two.

```
         one     one.1     one.2     one.3    one.4  ...     six.8     six.9    six.10  six.11    six.12
   0     0.000000   0.00000   0.00000  0.000000  0.00000  ...  0.029126  0.089431  0.009901     0.0  0.000000
   1     0.000000   0.00000   0.00000  0.020101  0.00000  ...  0.009709  0.048780  0.000000     0.0 -0.007519
   2     0.022263   0.00000   0.00000  0.038526  0.02444  ... -0.009709  0.000000  0.019802    -8.0  0.000000
   3     0.000000  32.00000  32.00000  0.038526  0.00000  ... -0.009709 -0.024390  0.029703   -16.0  0.000000
   4     0.000000   0.00000   0.00000  0.020101  0.14257  ...  0.000000 -0.016260  0.019802     8.0  0.015038
```

Inside my .csv file the data are arranged this way.

[image]

And the resulting plot I'm getting.
[image]

Comment: Pandas discourage duplicates column names. So when you read `csv`, the duplicated columns are enumerated.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found a way to overcome this was by renaming the name of classes with an integer at the end of name class like one1, one2, one3... So I can iterate over the columns classes and hidde all labels that was going to appear. This is how the dataset looks like now.

```
      one1      one2      one3      one4     one5  ...      six9     six10     six11  six12     six13
0     0.000000   0.00000   0.00000  0.000000  0.00000  ...  0.029126  0.089431  0.009901    0.0  0.000000
1     0.000000   0.00000   0.00000  0.020101  0.00000  ...  0.009709  0.048780  0.000000    0.0 -0.007519
2     0.022263   0.00000   0.00000  0.038526  0.02444  ... -0.009709  0.000000  0.019802   -8.0  0.000000
3     0.000000  32.00000  32.00000  0.038526  0.00000  ... -0.009709 -0.024390  0.029703  -16.0  0.000000
4     0.000000   0.00000   0.00000  0.020101  0.14257  ...  0.000000 -0.016260  0.019802    8.0  0.015038
```

And this is the code I use to plot:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    df = pd.read_csv(('output.csv'))
    for i in range(5, 10):
        plt.figure(5)
        plt.title("Campo Elétrico Classe six")
        ax = plt.gca()
        df.plot(label='_Hidden label', kind='line',y=f'six{i}', legend=False, ax=ax)    
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```